# Cannot programatically display built in Merge tool to resolve a merge conflict

Tags: c#, tfs, merge, tfs-sdk

I use Unit Testing project *VS 2012* and too an Console Application project *VS 2012* using **TeamFoundationClient 11.0** and **TFS 2008**.

I use ***MergeContent(Conflict, true)*** but not shown UI (dialog modal for merge).

I have seen this reference:

Cannot programatically display built in Merge tool to resolve a merge conflict 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783320/cannot-programatically-display-built-in-merge-tool-to-resolve-a-merge-conflict

Workspace.MergeContent() with useExternalMergeTool = true does not open the built in VS merge tool using VS 2012

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.mergecontent(v=vs.110).aspx

> Using VS 2010 with TFS 2010 without any User Tool configured for
>   performing a merge operation, when we call Workspace.MergeContent()
>   with useExternalMergeTool = true, the built in VS merge tool was used.
>
> Using VS 2012 with TFS 2012 without any User Tool configured for
>   performing a merge operation, when we call Workspace.MergeContent()
>   with useExternalMergeTool = true the function returns fals without
>   opening the built in VS merge tool. At last, unlike previous versions,
>   the VS 2012 built in merge tool is quite nice, but now there is no way
>   to open it programatically to resolve a merge conflict. This is
>   functional regression from VS 2010.

Any suggestions about it or any workaround for show modal dialog for merge content ?

Comment: Your question is really unclear. What does unit testing have to do with merging conflicts and modal dialog boxes? What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TFS API MergeContent returns false without showing merge tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160736/tfs-api-mergecontent-returns-false-without-showing-merge-tool)

Answer (score 0):

copy vsDiffMerge.exe from visual studio installation dir C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE inside App Exe file

```
var mergetool = new ThirdPartyToolDefinition(".*",ToolOperations.Merge,"vsDiffMerge.exe","","/m %1 %2 %3 %4");
var toolcol= ThirdPartyToolDefinitionCollection.Instance.FindTool(".*",ToolOperations.Merge);
if (toolcol == null)
   {
    ThirdPartyToolDefinitionCollection.Instance.AddTool(mergetool);
    ThirdPartyToolDefinitionCollection.Instance.PersistAllToRegistry();
   }

var controlsAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ControlAddItemsExclude));
var vcResolveCoinflictsDialogType = controlsAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.DialogResolveConflicts");
var ci = vcResolveCoinflictsDialogType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(Workspace), typeof(string[]), typeof(bool) }, null);
var resolveCoinflictsDialog = (Form)ci.Invoke(new object[] { workspace, null, true });
resolveCoinflictsDialog.ShowDialog(parent);

ThirdPartyToolDefinitionCollection.Instance.Remove(mergetool);
ThirdPartyToolDefinitionCollection.Instance.PersistAllToRegistry();
```