# Display 'Resolve Conflicts' window and merge tool in ASP.net MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, merge-conflict-resolution, tfs-sdk

We are building an ASP.Net MVC web app that interacts with TFS API.  When we do a merge through the API, it does not display the '**Resolve Conflicts**' window or the internal merge tool window. Can we force this window to come up in an ASP.Net MVC View and wait for user feedback from TFS internal merge tool ?

> workspace.MergeContent(conflict, true) --> is returning 'False'

without displaying the conflict resolution window.

*Note*: this window/functionality was working fine when our app was a desktop Windows forms application.

[Similar issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160736/tfs-api-mergecontent-returns-false-without-showing-merge-tool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no web equivalent of the conflict resolution window. That's why it worked when it was a desktop application and doesn't work anymore.